# My message in target queue is not readable in SQL Server Service Broker

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I am using Service broker to connect other domains in my system as you can see here i send a message to target service like this :

```
_ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"Declare @ConversationHandle uniqueidentifier

Begin Transaction
Begin Dialog @ConversationHandle
 From Service SenderService
 To Service 'ReceiverService'
 On Contract SampleContract
 WITH Encryption=off;
SEND 
      ON CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
      Message Type SenderMessageType
  ('<Reception>Add</Reception><OrganizationId>2</OrganizationId>') Commit");
```

In other hand i enable a SP to get the message like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ProcessTargetQueue] as
BEGIN
Declare @ConversationHandle as uniqueidentifier
Declare @MessageBody as nvarchar(max)
Declare @MessageType as sysname
declare @MessageBodyXML as xml


    WHILE (1=1)
    BEGIN

        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        WAITFOR (
           RECEIVE top (1)
      @MessageType = message_type_name,
      @ConversationHandle = conversation_handle,
    @MessageBody = message_body
FROM TargetQueue

        ), TIMEOUT 5000;

       IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BEGIN
              ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
              BREAK;
        END
if @MessageType = 'SenderMessageType'
      BEGIN
            SEND 
                  ON CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
                  Message Type ReceiverMessageType
                  ('Message is received')
            END Conversation @ConversationHandle

        set @MessageBodyXML=    (select cast(@MessageBody as xml)  )

      insert into s (s1) select CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @MessageBodyXML)

   END


        COMMIT TRANSACTION;




     END  

    END
```

as you see i insert the message_body into `s1` table ,but when i check the table i can't see the messages.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is inserting a varchar value into the binary message_body:

```
SEND 
      ON CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
      Message Type SenderMessageType
  ('<Reception>Add</Reception><OrganizationId>2</OrganizationId>') Commit");
```

But this code is casting the binary value as `nvarchar` so the value is misinterpreted:

```
insert into s (s1) select CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @MessageBodyXML)
```

One way to fix this is to specify the `N` prefix so the xml string is a Unicode literal:

```
SEND 
      ON CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
      Message Type SenderMessageType
  (N'<Reception>Add</Reception><OrganizationId>2</OrganizationId>') Commit");
```

Comment: Just to add another idea to the solution, put you message in an XML-typed variable and then use that variable in the SEND statement.